# If an action card turns a planet neutral, are the space docks and PDS units on it destroyed?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

If an opponent plays a card such as Local Unrest and targets my last ground force on the planet, that planet is turned neutral.  When that happens, do I lose any PDS's and Space Docks on that planet, or do they remain?  If my forces remain there, do I regain control when I land ground forces there again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Space Docks and PDS units are destroyed.**

From page 3 of the official [FAQ version 2.3](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/site/support/ti3faq2-3.pdf)

> Q: If a planet contains one Ground Force, one Space Dock, and one PDS,
>   and “Local Unrest” is played on that planet, are the Space Dock and
>   PDS destroyed?
>
> A: Yes. The Space Dock and PDS would be destroyed due
>   to the planet changing ownership (becoming neutral).

And for good measure, on page 12 of the [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3rules.pdf):

> If a PDS unit lands alone on a neutral or enemy planet, it is
>   immediately destroyed.